# How to pass language information from page to page?

Tags: cookies, internationalization

If I have a multilingual site, what is the best way to pass information about language?

Right now the language is saved in cookies. That's convenient except that might be not good for search optimization, if search bots don't use cookies.

The other option would be specifying language in address, like `exampel.com/?lang=de`, but then you probably need to add `?lang=xx` to every link on the page.

Is there a right way?

Answer (score 2):

Better way is to maintain this info in `session`,

> The other option would be specifying
>   language in address, like
>   exampel.com/?lang=de, but then you
>   probably need to add ?lang=xx to every
>   link on the page.
>
> Is there a right way?

I would have created filter than parse each request and fetches the `lang` param and process accordingly.

Moreover I would recommend you to use following url pattern, and get the lang from filter

```
yourapp.com/en/welcome/
```

Comment: but is it search-bot-friendly?

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the content crawlable then you'd have to pass it in the URL. Either as a parameter `http://mydomain.com/en/english-content` or maybe have separate sites/subdomains `http://english.mydomain.com/english-content`

Answer (score 1):

I would use Wikepedia's approach: Different URLs for different languages.
http://en.wikipedia.org for english
http://es.wikipedia.org for Spanish